# Cannot update JAR properties file with Install4j

Tags: install4j

I created a new *"Configuration form"* screen which contains several text inputs. My goal is to use these inputs variables and merge them into a properties file.

I'm using version 6.1.6 - so I created *"Modify a ZIP file"* action for that purpose and placed it under the installer's Install files.
In the *"Modification actions"* property of the action I created new *"Write properties to file"* action and inside it under the *"Source of property definitions*" I choose the *Installer variable option*. It then let me bound the variables I defined earlier which makes sense.

My problem is after running the installer the properties file won't get update. When opening the installation.log I have the next message:

```
[ERROR] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.properties.WritePropertiesFileAction [ID 1540]: Properties source variable db.database is not an instance of java.util.Map
```

1. How can I define the variable to be as a Map type?
2. I wasn't sure about where exactly place the "Modify a ZIP file" action - is keeping it under the *Install files* section is fine or should I place it right under the new "Configuration form" I created?

**UPDATE**:

I set my variable name to be: "${installer:db.database}" which should place it within a Map and now I'm still getting an error:

```
[ERROR] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.properties.WritePropertiesFileAction [ID 1540]: Properties source variable postgres has not been set
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> under the "Source of property definitions" I choose the Installer variable option.

In that case you would have to set an installer variable to a map with all variable definitions that should be saved to the property file.

I would rather set the "Source of property definitions" property to "Direct entry". In the "Property definitions" child property add definitions for all properties like this:

```
A=${installer:A}
B=${installer:B}
...
```

Comment: It works, thanks!
I have another small question please. In the properties file I have the next property:
**db.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432**
In the configuration form I created 2 inputs: 1 is for the server URL and another for the server port. In the properties file they are both on the same property (localhost:5432). Is there any way update each part separately without creating new property in the properties file?

Comment: The installer variables are simply replaced in the "Property definitions" property, so `db.url=${installer:host}:${installer:port}` should be what you need.